# Retrieving the URL of a list item's display form and ID in javascript using sharepoint

Tags: javascript, list, url, sharepoint

Currently I have tried to break the URL down into parts:

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(oList);
for(var n in items)
{..
     var itemURL = window.location.protocol +'//'+ window.location.host 
     +'/'+ oList.Title +'/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + items[n].id;
..}
```

This outputs the oList.Title part as *undefined* and the site also has a subsite within it that needs to be included. Highlighted in bold are the changeable fields:

```
http://sharepoint_site/sub_site/**current_document_lib**/forms/dispform.aspx?**ID=1**
```

Currently it outputs as:

```
http://sharepoint_site/undefined/forms/dispform.aspx?ID=1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And you are using sharepoint 2010?

Comment: using 2013, seem to have solved the problem by using window.location.href and replacing 'AllItems' with 'DispForm' using replace()

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by using window.location.href and replacing 'AllItems' with 'DispForm' using replace():

```
 var finalURL = itemURL.replace('AllItems', 'DispForm');
```